# Is the the Turkish word kin 'hate, venom etc' restricted to Anatolian-Turkish only?

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, borrowing, turkic-languages

The word kin 'hate, venom, spite' is quite unusual and took my attention for its meaning 'venom'. Is it an Anatolian-Turkish/Azeri only word or is it common in other Turkic languages? Does anyone know of any commentary on its etymology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot answer the first part of your question, but as far as etymology goes it is very straight-forward: it is from Persian kīn “hatred” (from Middle Persian kēn, Avestan kaēna- “revenge”).

Comment: Thank you! I accept that as an answer. The first question would have a purpose for me if the etymology was unknown. In that case I would suspect a loan, possibly from N. Caucasus.

Comment: You can check http://kubbealtilugati.com/ for etymology

Answer (score 3):

I totally agree with fdb. Although I cannot say if it is used in Central Asian Turkic Languages( Turkmen, Uzbek and Uighur), for certain I can say that (not sure about today but) it existed in Azerbaijani. Look at the example from Fuzuli: "*Gam değil ehl-i garaz eylerse benden men’-i hayr / Gam değil ehl-i hased bağlarsa ben miskîne **kin***"

edit: A quick search revelead that it is used in Uzbek, Bashkurt, Tatar (no Crimean), Turkmen and Azerbaijani. http://tdk.gov.tr/index.php?option=com_lehceler&arama=lehceler&guid=TDK.LHC.58cd91f5221869.95997362

edit2: Appereantly the search function is a script here is a screen cap [image]